# How to know the last function/file/line core dump of linux on windows machine?

Tags: linux, coredump

So I have a Linux core dump, from an embedded linux machine. I have the corresponding symbol file. Problem is I need to write a tool that will find the file/line/function where the crash occurred, on a windows machine.

Can not use readymade tool.

I am looking for information on how to do it OR some script that I can read to know how to do it.

Answer (score 0):

Use the BFD library (or try to grok the source code) from GNU binutils to parse the [ELF Core format](http://sourceware.org/cgi-bin/cvsweb.cgi/src/bfd/elfcore.h?rev=1.31&content-type=text/x-cvsweb-markup&cvsroot=src).